# Prove a property of positive strongly convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $f$ be a smooth map from 3-dim manifold $M$ to $M'$ as submanifold of $R^4$, i.e. $f: M \rightarrow M' \subset R^4$. Suppose we have a positive and strongly convex norm function $\Phi$ on $R^4$ which induce a positive and strongly convex norm function $\Phi$ on the tangent space of $M'$ and smooth on the tangent bundle $TM'$.
(Just like Euclidean metric induce an inner product on the submanifold of $R^3$)

Here positive and strongly convex norm mean that (1)$\Phi(v) \geq 0$, (2)$\Phi(cv) = c\Phi(v)$ for $c \geq 0 $ and (3) Hessian $\frac{\partial^2 \Phi^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(v)$ is positive definite for every $v \in R^4$, and $x_i, x_j$ are coordinate charts in $R^4$. (which induce that Hessian $\frac{\partial^2 \Phi^2}{\partial v_i \partial v_j}(v)$ is positive definite for every $v \in T_{f(p)} M'$, and $v_i, v_j$ are coordinate charts in $T_{f(p)} M'$. And we can also deduce that unit sphere of $\Phi$ is convex).

Besides, we have following conditions:

1. $d_{\tilde{v}} \Phi(d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$ for every $v, w \in T_p M$.
2. $d_{\tilde{v}} \Phi(d_p^3 f(v, w, w_1)) + d_{\tilde{v}}^2 \Phi(d_p^2 f(v, w), d_p^2 f(v, w_1)) = 0 $ for every $v, w, w_1 \in T_p M$.

Here $\tilde{v} = d_p f(v)$

The question is:
Can we use these conditions to prove that if for every pair $v, w \in T_p M$ which satisfies that $d_p^2 f(v, w)$ is in the tangent space $T_p M$, we have $d_p^2 f(v, w) = 0$?

$\\$

This question has two backgrounds:

1. If it is 2-dim manifold, then from $d_{\tilde{v}} \Phi(d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$ and $d_{\tilde{w}} \Phi(d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$, we can manage to prove this.
2. If it is Riemannian metric rather than this norm, then this is equivalent to the condition that first and second derivative of Riemannian metric are zero. So Christopher symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$ and we can deduce that $d_p^2 f(v, w) = L_{ij} N$ with $L_{ij}$ as second fundamental form and get that $d_p^2 f(v, w) = 0$ if it is in $T_p M$

Comment: Your notation is totally confusing and non-standard. You're evidently writing $d_pf^2$ for $d_p^2f$, i.e., the Hessian of $f$. Your misunderstanding is in the body of the text, too. It is $\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial v_i\partial v_j}$. (Remember that in basic calculus you wrote $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$.) I also don't understand what $v_i$ means; you're choosing *some* coordinate system on the tangent space of $M'$ (which you have also not defined). Please revise.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, thank you. $\frac{\partial^2 \Phi^2}{\partial v_i \partial v_j}$ is actually definition of Finsler norm. For other notations, I corrected the confusing ones.